# The Order of the Identity of a Group

Tags: group-theory, soft-question

My lecture notes say that in a group $G$, the identity $e$ is the only element of $G$ which has order $1$.

I would like to know why the order of $e$ is said to be $1$, when it could clearly be $0$ since the identity $e$ acted on itself zero times is just $e$.

Is it valid to think about an element acting on itself zero times? So for example is it valid to even think about why $e^0 = e$? Cheers.

Comment: If $g$ is any element, then $g^0=e$. So should every $g$ have order zero?

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown Shouldn't any $g^0 = g$? We are taking an element of the group, $g$, and doing nothing with it. We just get back $g$.

Comment: So then $g=g^1=g^{0+1}=g^0g^1=gg=g^2$???

Comment: Yeah, it makes no sense, but I think you're using notation that relies on the foundation that $g^0 = e$. I'm not sure about this explanation since my question is more to do with the fundamentals. But I see that it is convenient to define the order of $e$ to be $1$.

Comment: @TristanBatchler Are you familiar with the fact that for any real number $x$, $x^0=1$? 'Raising to the power 0' isn't the same as 'doing nothing' in any part of mathematics.

Comment: @dbmag9 Haha yeah I'm familiar with that. I just thought that in group theory it was different since $g^n$ is really notation that hides $g \circ g \circ ... \circ g$ ($n$ times, $\circ$ is the group action). So really $g^n$ was described to me as $g$ acting on itself $n$ times. So in my mind, $g^0$ should be $g$ acting on itself no times which I intuitively interpreted as just $g$.

Comment: @TristanBatchler Using that analogy, $g^0$ would be an 'empty product', rather than anything about $g$ acting on itself.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The order of an element is a positive integer, by definition.

Comment: Thanks. This was not in my lecture notes so it got me thinking. I now realise it even says it must be positive on the wikipedia page, which I should have paid more attention to. Sorry!

Comment: To clarify, this would be one of those rules that does not fit into the formula like @TristanBatchler has presented, so we have an addendum for input is identity?

Answer (score 8):

Don't think of $g^0$ as representing $g$ acting on itself $0$ times but as $g$ acting on something else $0$ times.  Groups frequently represent actions on other objects.  An important class of examples is symmetry groups.

Consider G as the group of symmetries of a square and $g \in G$ as *rotate clockwise by $90^\circ$*.  Then *$g^2$ is rotate clockwise by $180^\circ$* and $g^3$ is *rotate clockwise by $270^\circ$*.  So, what is a sensible definition of $g^0$ in this context?  Well, *rotate by $0^\circ$*.  Similarly we can sensibly define $g^{-1}$ as *rotate anticlockwise by $90^\circ$* since this will undo the effect of $g$.  With these definitions, $g^n$ is *rotate clockwise by $n \times 90^\circ$* whether $n$ is positive, zero, or negative and $g^m \times g^n = g^{m+n}$ and life is good.  With your convention, things would not be so neat.

So, with this convention, $g^0$ is always $e$ and hence to be useful we must require the order to be $> 0$ and not just $\geq 0$.

Answer (score 3):

You can define powers of a group element $g$: $g^0=e$ and $g^{n+1}=g^n\cdot g$ for $n\geq 0$. The order of an element is chosen to be $\geq 1$.

Comment: But why define $g^0 = e$? Thinking about it, one would define any $g^0 = g$ because we are taking an element of the group, $g$ and doing nothing with it. We just get back $g$. At least that makes more sense in my mind...

Comment: @Tristan Batchler Why force the issue when in fact the order is defined the least positive integer $n$ for which $g^n=e$,

Comment: Whoops, I guess I missed the part here the order had to be a positive integer. This was not in my lecture notes so it got me thinking.

Comment: @TristanBatchler $g^0$, interpreted literally, is the product of $0$ copies of $g$, not "doing nothing" with $g$. This is an instance of the "empty product", which for various reasons is defined to be the identity element. Here is one argument: We should be able to replace $g^n$ with $n$ copies of $g$. So $hg^n$ should be the same as $hg\dots g$, where $g$ is repeated $n$ times. Setting $n=0$, we get $hg^0 = h$. Similarly, we should have $g^0h = h$. This means $g^0$ is the identity element. This isn't a proof, just a reason for the definition, and it doesn't work for negative values of $n$.

Answer (score 0):

In my book, the order of an element is the order of the cyclic group it generates, so the identity clearly has order 1.